# Mysql increase column size

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I am using mysql version 5.5.31-0+wheezy1-log, below is my table structure.
I want url Column to store 100 character information, currently it is storing max 55 character information with space, which I am viewing in phpmyadmin (version 3.4.11.1deb2).
I have tried to change url `Column Type varchar(255) to MEDIUMTEXT` but it didn't worked as I was expecting.
Please suggest.

```
#  Column   Type          Collation        Attributes  Null  Default            Extra  
1  id       int(7)                                     No    None               AUTO_INCREMENT  
2  site     varchar(255)  utf8_unicode_ci              No    None     
3  url      varchar(255)  utf8_unicode_ci              No    None     
4  time     timestamp                                  No    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     
5  ip       varchar(255)  utf8_unicode_ci              No    None     
6  Country  varchar(255)  utf8_unicode_ci              No    None
```

Thank you.

Comment: Max width of `VARCHAR` in MySQL 5.5 is 65536, so no need for `TEXT` here.

Comment: Do you mean that your `varchar(255)` can't hold more than 55 chars or its a typo in the info you've provided?

Comment: I am getting query part of URL to store in column url.For e.g., if query is "how to get general knowledge information updated August 2013" when I check in phpmyadmin it shows only "how to get general knowledge information updated A..."

Comment: I have exported table to csv, it's fine, all contents are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings will never exceed some upper limit of characters, then go with `VARCHAR` because it will be faster and more efficient. If you need more space, go with `TEXT`. If you aren't sure how much space your text will take up, you should probably go with `TEXT`; the performance difference isn't that large, and it's better to be future-proof than risk having to change it later when your requirements change.

Comment: I have tried to change `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` but when I check in phpmyadmin, url column is not showing complete query part. For e.g., if query is "how to get general knowledge information updated August 2013" when I check in phpmyadmin it shows only "how to get general knowledge information updated A..." I have checked character count in MS Word 53 with spaces.

Comment: I have exported table to csv, it's fine, all contents are showing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about the table you paste, I guess this is what you want, so you can use the `ALTER TABLE` query to modify the maximum size of a column:

```
 ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY url VARCHAR(255);
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html